# Custom sort between two models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to sort 'entries' based upon the employee ID  `adj_service_date`.

Each entry is made by an employee. I take the `emp_id` then loop through my users model to get the `person_id` then use the `person_id` to get the `adj_service_date`. Then, after that, I want to sort the entries by the `adj_service_date`, (when they started working), which belongs to my EmpComp model.

I am having some trouble figuring out how to do this correctly.

This is my Entry controller:

```
def pending_sort
  @start_of_month = Date.current.beginning_of_week
  @mgr_section = MgrSection.where("manager_first = ? and manager_last = ?", current_user.emp_first_name, current_user.emp_last_name).pluck(:mgr_sectio$

  #-----Pending table sort by adj_service_date----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @ent_f = Entry.where("section = ? and leave_start <= ? and approve_disapprove = ?", @mgr_section, start_of_month, '3').pluck(:emp_id)
  @ent_sort = Entry.where("section = ? and leave_start <= ? and approve_disapprove = ?", @mgr_section, start_of_month, '3')
  @ent_f.map do |es|
    @person = User.where("emp_id = ?", es).pluck(:person_id)
    @person.map do |pid|
     servd = Empcomp.where("person_id = ?", pid).order('adj_service_date DESC')
     serva = Empcomp.where("person_id = ?", pid).order('adj_service_date ASC')


      # I tried this but it didnt seem to work either ...

     @ent_pend = @ent_sort.sort{|a, b| a.servd <=> b.serva }



    end
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # _pending_sort.html.haml
    format.js
  end
  #render :pending_sort 
end
```

## Models that belong to Entry

```
User 
EmpComp
```

## Demo

Lets say I have Bill Bob Henry as my employees the each have coresponding person_id in my user model so for bill = 12345 for bob = 12444 and henry = 98888 each person id will then be used called into my EmpComp model to find bills bobs and henrys adj service date .

With that Bill has 3 entries Bob has 2 entrys and Henry has 1 entry

Now with that data I want to use my empcomp model and sort each entry based off bill bob and henrys adj_service_date

Bill adj_service_date  March 1999

bob  adj_service_date  September 2013

henry adj_service_date  May 2015

so in my view for @ent_pend the entries should be grouped by adj_service_date from emp_comp model

Basically sorting it by seniority of what year they were hired.

Bill entry

Bill entry

Bill entry

Bob entry

Bob entry

Henry entry

Comment: Please post a better context: show us the model's relations, the relevant attributes of each models concerned, and what should be the result at the end

Comment: I updated my question. @MrYoshiji